# String concatenates with another after strcpy for the latter

Tags: arrays, c, string, struct, strcpy

As you can see in my code bellow I don't mess with `e[i].politico` in the for cycle where my problem occurs, but for some reason, after perfoming a strcpy onto `e[i].risco` of a predifined char array, `e[i].politico` gets appended with `e[i].risco`'s content. I can't really find the reason why this happens. Any guidance in debugging is appreciated.

Struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int ent;
    char nome[50];
    int cc;
    int nif;
    char naci[50];
    char resii[50];
    char politico[3];
    char risco[50];
} ENT;
```

Where i scan for `e[i].politico`:

```
scanf(" %d", &aux);


if (aux == 1) {
    char s[] = "SIM";
    strcpy(e[i].politico, s);
} else {
    char n[] = "NAO";
    strcpy(e[i].politico, n);
}
printf("1-%s ", e[i].politico);//Value is correct ("SIM")
```

Where the code fails:

```
int aux, i;

for (i = 0; i < sizeoficial; i++) {

    for (aux = 0; aux < 3; aux++) {

        printf("\nBefore get in IF => %s", e[i].politico);//Value is correct ("SIM")
        if (strcmp(e[i].naci, riskhigh[aux]) == 0 || strcmp(e[i].resii, riskhigh[aux]) == 0 || strcmp(e[i].politico, "SIM") == 0) {

            char r[] = "RISCO ALTO";
            printf("\nBefore strcpy => %s", e[i].politico);//Value is correct ("SIM")
            strcpy(e[i].risco, r);
            printf("\nRisco  => %s", e[i].risco);//Value is correct ("RISCO ALTO")
            printf("\nAfter strcpy => %s", e[i].politico);//Value is wrong("SIMRISCO ALTO")

            break;
        } else if ((strcmp(e[i].naci, riskmed[aux]) == 0 || strcmp(e[i].resii, riskmed[aux]) == 0) &&
                   strcmp(e[i].risco, "RISCO ALTO") != 0) {
            char r[] = "RISCO MEDIO";
            strcpy(e[i].risco, r);
        } else {
            char r[] = "RISCO BAIXO";
            strcpy(e[i].risco, r);
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: `"SIM"` requires four chars for storage, including the terminator. You're only giving it three. Change `char politico[3];` to `char politico[4];` and retest.

Comment: Yes, that solved it, my bad for not understanding how memory is used... Thank you